# What does B格 mean?

Tags: meaning, word, slang, internet-slang

In the [following answer over 知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/21360241/answer/26685442):

> 我在美国，异国恋，一直在坚持，克服孤独的最好办法只能是享受孤独吧。这可能是略有**B格**的一句话，可当我真正到了国外学习，发现没有太好的办法来克服孤独，是我境界不高，还是我乐趣恶俗，的确始终找不到好的办法。大家都很忙，就算有朋友也很难照顾彼此，百分之九十五的时候是一个人去完成一项事情，不准剽窃，不准作弊，严格的制度和偏执的诚信，都让人喘不过气。

What does *B格* mean? I'm sure it is an Internet slang, but not sure what it means.

According to [百度百科](https://baike.baidu.com/item/B%E6%A0%BC/15633485?fr=aladdin):

> “B格”，网络熟词，亦写作“逼格”“13格”等，为网络语言“装13的格调”的简称。

But then what does it mean...?

Comment: bkrs: 逼格 (Ru)slang. (high) level of expertise in pretense,hypocrisy   
格调① 指不同作家或不同作品的艺术特点的综合表现：格调高稚。
② 〈书〉指人的风格或品格。
(1) [literary or artistic style]∶诗歌的格律声调。 亦泛指作品的艺术风格
先定格调
格调豪放
这部影片低级庸俗, 格调不高
格调高雅
(2) [one's style of work as well as one's moral quality]∶人的风格或品格
谁爱风流高格调, 共怜时世俭梳妆。 --《唐诗纪事·秦韬玉》
(3) [form; style]∶格式; 式样
山势和水势在这里别是一种格调, 变化而又和谐。 --《雨中登泰山》

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a net language. It's like *poser* noun and *pretentious* adjective in English. It reminds me a similar word: zhuang-bility(装逼)， which denotes the same meaning. B格 is just the extent of zhuang-bility(装逼).

So, 略有B格的一句话 means *the sentence with a tone of being slightly pretentious*.

Comment: What do you mean "zhuang-bility", not "zhuang-bi"?

Comment: @Blaszard, "zhuang-bility" is coined by some Chinese people. It stands for the English version of "zhuang-bi"(装逼), because -bility is a standard suffix in English. "zhuang-bility" is more interesting than "zhuang-bi" in a sense of humor.

Comment: As a matter of fact, using zhuang-bility instead zhuang-bi is also a form of 有B格.

Answer (score 0):

A close reading the text convinced me "B格" stands for "蔽隔“--isolation. One meaning of 蔽 (bì) is "hidden", and "隔 (gé) means "cut off". The writer of that passage is talking about how he/she deals with the sense of isolation (and maybe alienation) living in a foreign country where everyone (including friends) is busy, so he/she is left to his/her own devices to deal with the sense of isolation. In the quoted text, the writer approaches the topic as an intellectual subject matter, pondering whether it's his/her own lack of high-minded areas of interest that exacerbated his/her loneliness ("是我境界不高，还是我乐趣恶俗").